# How can I write a startup script for OSX?

Tags: macos, script, boot

I'm unfamiliar with how this works with OSX. I just want a script to run whenever the OS loads up. Simple script to restart my servers via python. There's about 4 of them. So how do I run commands like the following at startup?

```
cd Applications/MyServer
python myserver.py

cd Applications/MyOtherServer
python myotherserver.py
```

and so on? I don't know where to place the script, or what type of file to save it in :/

UPDATE:
ok i figured out that its just a matter of dumping that into a text file with an extension of .sh. Then running the sh myScript.sh command. But I'm still hunting for an answer how to get this to run at startup.

UPDATE:
here's my script to start my servers. I'm still looking for a way to get it into startup. had to do them in separate windows as the application will then run in this window.

```
# Start up Server 1
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "python /applications/Server1/server1.py"
end tell'

# Start up Server 2
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "python /applications/server2/server2.py"
end tell'

# Start up Server 3
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "python /applications/server3/server3.py"
end tell'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol ok...

so the answer was simply to make the .sh file executable by running

```
chmod a+x LaunchServers.sh
```

Then associating the file type to run with terminal, then adding it to startup items under Users & Groups in system prefs. Tested and working.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I didn't test this but it has a chance of actually working ;)

- create a runnable script
- go to Preferences -> "Users and Groups" -> Your user -> "Login Items" tab
- Drag and drop your script into the list of items to run.
- reboot